# Is there a way to password-protect Dropbox settings (preferences) on a local Windows computer?

Tags: windows-8.1, dropbox, password-protection

I want to load my Dropbox account on my wife's laptop, but only make certain folders available. (I have a pro account with 1TB of space, and she only has a free account with 4 GB, which is why I want to load my account on her laptop. The files I want to share with her are many GB larger than what her free account supports.) It's easy for me to set up my account on her laptop; I just need connect her laptop (running Windows 8.1) to my Dropbox account and then select the specific folders I want in the Dropbox preferences.

The problem is the security with this. I don't trust that my wife uses her laptop sufficiently securely. There's no big deal if someone unauthorized gets access to the particular folders that I want to enable on my wife's laptop. However, I am concerned that if someone physically accesses her computer, they might then go into the Dropbox settings and then enable any of my other folders, most of which I doon't want anyone to access.

Thus, I'm looking for a way to password-protect Dropbox settings so that even if someone has physical access to her laptop, they would need a password to change any of the settings. I can't find if Dropbox has a built-in password for this. If not, is there any other solution I could use for this?

I'm aware of the possibility of password-protecting a Dropbox crypt, such as suggested here: [Is there a way I can password protect a dropbox directory on my work pc?](https://superuser.com/questions/282794/is-there-a-way-i-can-password-protect-a-dropbox-directory-on-my-work-pc).
However, I'm not ready to go that far just yet. All I want is to password-protect the Dropbox settings on a local computer.

Comment: Why don't you just set her up with her own account, then share the folders you want shared? That way, no-one except you can get to the others.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I've edited the question with the clarification: I have a pro account and she does not; I want to share many GBs of files with her. In fact, what you suggested is what I've been doing up till now, and we've hit our limit. I don't want to pay for another pro account just for this.

Comment: ah, OK - makes sense. I've never had a business-style account, but is it not possible to set up 'employees' with limited privileges/folders?

Comment: @Tetsujin, I don't quite understand your question in the context of my question. I know that my wife has insecure laptop practices (like not using passwords), and I'm looking for a way to sync certain Dropbox folders onto her potentially insecure computer, and yet avoid compromising the rest of the folders in my Dropbox.

Comment: "Dropbox for Business gives IT admins comprehensive audit logs to track what's being shared and who's sharing it. Easy-to-use controls restrict access," from https://www.dropbox.com/business/why-dropbox-for-business

Comment: Thanks, @Tetsujin, for the suggestion, but Dropbox for Business is far more expensive than just paying for a second pro account for my wife! So, it doesn't solve the cost aspect of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late for your request, but I faced similar situation.

So, I've created kind of workaround (for Windows only, sorry).

This solution is controlling access to menu in Dropbox client (Desktop app).

After installing this solution, if user tries to access menu in Dropbox client - password is requested. If password is correct, access to menu is allowed for 60 seconds. After that interval passes, password is again requested.

In that way you could select which folders should be synced and then password protect access to Dropbox menu where user could change that preference, so user on that computer could access only data in synced folder that  you selected.

Solution is freeware for personal and business use, hope you find it useful.

If you have any problem, feel free to contact me.

Please find details at [www.pem2.com/DCAC](http://www.pem2.com/DCAC)

Comment: *So, I've created kind of workaround (for Windows only, sorry).* @MarijuanaTechnologyIT420 I think it's his software.

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding. I created this software for problem that I could not find solution. It's third party software that could help Dropbox users with request to password protect Dropbox Client (Dropbox Desktop Application) preferences/settings.

Comment: I'm not sure if my answer was comment or answer in regard to "Why do I need..." since I believe that it's answer to Ochado's question. Details are available at web page from my answer, but in essence it's software that control if user tries to access menu in Dropbox client and prohibit access if user does not enter correct password. Password can be, of course, changed in software.

Comment: I've installed the software, but how do I run it, or even set up the password? I can't find any instructions on what to do after installation.

Comment: After installation, software should be running automatically. Please try to access Dropbox menu. It should start window and ask you for password. Default password is stated on web page under Technical details. If window is not started please check if service "Dropbox Client Access Control Service" is running (type services.msc in command prompt) and please start it manually if, for some reason, it's not started. If you have any trouble please reply.

Comment: I forgot to mention that software should be invisible until Dropbox Client menu is accessed. On that event software should activate it's window and ask for password (and also on menu there is option to change default/current password).