# Is the EFS key of all accounts associated with the same Microsoft account the same?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, encryption, efs

My boot hard drive stopped working but I had backed up all the files on an external hard drive and encrypted it with EFS prior to this. I unfortunately did not make a backup of the key and so was wondering if could decrypt the files using another computer running the same Microsoft account.

So is this possible?

Comment: No. See the dupe question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who can decrypt EFS files?](http://superuser.com/questions/186008/who-can-decrypt-efs-files)

Comment: @DavidPostill Why not? Same Microsft account means same Password and Username, which means the password stored in SAM is the same. That is what is basicly given in the answer. Or is my logic completely off course? Explain please.

Comment: "This is because the local user's password hashes, stored in the SAM file, are encrypted with the Syskey, and the Syskey value is not available to an offline attacker who does not possess the Syskey passphrase/floppy."

Comment: There is more than one level of encryption. I suspect you may also have to take into account the account [SID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier)s will aslo be different on different machines.

Comment: @Don'tRoothereplz: But the EFS key is not based on the password in any way at all. It's merely encrypted _with_ the password.

Comment: Ok, Finally Understood.

Comment: @DavidPostill Though the duplicate question may have the answer embedded in it, it does not answer the question directly, since there is no mention of linked Microsoft accounts.

Comment: @DavidPostill You were wrong about this. I just encrypted a few files on my **new** desktop with EFS. When I accessed those files over the network from my other computer, the user that was associated with my MS account managed to decrypt them. I tried accessing them from other accounts and it gave me *Access is denied* errors as expected. I have the Anniversary update. On the other hand, this does open a security hole.

Comment: @Don'tRoothereplz... I'm happy to be proved wrong. You can, of course, [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can access files encrypted with EFS over devices associated with the same Microsoft account without exporting and installing the required Certificates.